# Overlay on image issue

Tags: html, css

Need some help with an image overlay. I made a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7upzLdee/1/

```
<div class="rss-output" style="float:">
<div class="body"> 
<div class="overlay-feed"></div>
<div class="imagefix" style="float:none;">
<a target="_blank" href="#">
<img  src="http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/CMS/StaticContent/1391099215267_hero2.jpg" alt="" height="337" width="600"/></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>

div.rss-output {
float: left;
width: 33.333%;
position: relative;
padding: 15px !important;
overflow: hidden;
}

.rss-output .body {
width: 100%;
}

.rss-output .overlay-feed {
background: #000 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
z-index: 1;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
opacity: 0.5;
}

div.imagefix {
height: 200px;
line-height: 250px;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}

div.imagefix img {
margin: -50%;
}
```

I cannot figure out why the overlay is going over the image on the right side. I've tried many things but no luck.

All help appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `position: relative` for `.rss-output .body`

```css
div.rss-output {
    float: left;
    width: 33.333%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.rss-output .body {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.rss-output .overlay-feed {
    background: #000 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

div.imagefix {
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

div.imagefix img {
    margin: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="rss-output" style="float:">
<div class="body"> 
    <div class="overlay-feed"></div>
    <div class="imagefix" style="float:none;">
        <a target="_blank" href="#">
            <img src="http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/CMS/StaticContent/1391099215267_hero2.jpg" alt="" height="337" width="600"/></a>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

added `position:relative;` to body, because, when you use `position:absolute;` on some element, it will ignore static parents and therefore its width

```css
div.rss-output {
    float: left;
    width: 33.333%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.rss-output .body {
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
}

.rss-output .overlay-feed {
    background: #000 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

div.imagefix {
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

div.imagefix img {
    margin: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="rss-output" style="float:">
<div class="body"> 
    <div class="overlay-feed"></div>
    <div class="imagefix" style="float:none;">
        <a target="_blank" href="#">
            <img src="http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/CMS/StaticContent/1391099215267_hero2.jpg" alt="" height="337" width="600"/></a>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with overlay width.

```
.rss-output .overlay-feed {
    background: #000 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 89%;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

do overlay width 89%.[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sonam185/nvwpwdax/1/)

Comment: If I do that the overlay goes under the image I need it over the image and same size...